# Looking for time management / calendar software, maintained, opensource, fresh design

Tags: software-recommendation, calendar, korganizer

I am looking for some software recommendations:

I need a software that lets me organize my time in a kind of To-Do list style, some points it should include:

- "I need to do this... on that date."
- "how much progress did I make on task xyz?"
- "how does my schedule for next week look?"
- "how much time did I spend on xyz (activity) - time tracking"
- "what is most urgent? (priority)"
- google calendar support (would be nice)
- attach notes / files to a task

An open source solution would be the best, a good (fresh / (material)) design also. Native Linux client is a must, Android client preferably.

Thank you very much.

Comment: How  important is it to have it offline? There are plenty of web--based alternatives.

Comment: Not so important, would be nice but tell me :)

Comment: I hunted for many tools over the past couple of years and eventually settled on Todoist - which integrates into chrome and gmail and has an android version. http://todoist.com - the second runner up was Any.do - but a year ago I switched to Todoist because Any.do still didn't have some important features I needed. You could check them out - http://www.any.do

Answer (score 1):

Kimai is a tool I used for my clients a lot:
http://www.kimai.org/

Web based open source!

Meanwhile only the times i am in the company are important, so i use TrackWorkTime from F-Droid:
http://www.zephyrsoft.org/trackworktime

It is a wifi acess point based login logoff tracking tool which makes everything automatic which i need.

But for getting all mentioned things done i would recommend redmine:
http://www.redmine.org